# Developing Eclipse RCP with IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, eclipse-rcp

As a Java developer I dislike Eclipse as a (Java) IDE but I like the Eclipse RCP platform and I would like to build an application upon Eclipse RCP.

Is there a feasible way to develope Eclipse RCP applications in IntelliJ? I do understand that I might have to do some of the configuration in Eclipse but I would like do the most of coding in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible/hard to develop/configure Eclipse RCP using Intellij-Idea.

1. plugin.xml configures the required dependencies. If you open an rcp project there `Plug-in Dependencies` below `JRE System Library`.
2. The `Plug-in Dependencies` will contain the jar files required for the eclipse rcp project. The jar files will be added in it when dependencies in plugin.xml is added.
3. `.product` file won't be recognized in IntelliJ which is used for running or exporting the product.
4. There are quite a lot of things like `Activator, E4LifeCycle` classes which is hard to configure in IntelliJ.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146711/how-to-use-intellij-idea-for-eclipse-plugin-development